# Filemaker mail script text with fields and functions

Tags: email, script, filemaker

I trying to send an e-mail with the filemaker 10 "send mail" script template.

Is it possible to define in the message box text with fields and functions?

Example:

```
Hello Richard

This is a text List

Product: Product::Name
Customer: Lookup(Product Customer::Name;"Not found")

Greetings
Tony
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can! The 'message' field for the email is just the same as a calculation field. You can use the same notation and references to a field or a function. You can type this in the field to get you example:

```
"Hello Richard¶¶" & 

"This is a text List¶¶" & 

"Product: " & Product::Name & "¶" & 
"Customer: " & Lookup(Product Customer::Name; "Not Found") & "¶¶" & 

"Greetings¶" & 
"Tony"
```

I hope this will help you, despite this being a old question.

See the docs: http://www.filemaker.com/help/13/fmp/en/html/scripts_ref2.37.70.html#1029660